# Is it possible in JS to add to an html element some classes and remove some other classes in one line?

Tags: javascript, html, class, methods

Wonder if there's any functional equivalent of `some_element.classList.add("some_class", "some_other_class).remove("some_other_other_class")` line.

And I know that the `.toggle()` method would be a solution in some cases, but I wonder if there's a way to use exactly `.add()` and `.remove()` on one line.

Comment: Why you even need it?

Comment: @VaheYavrumian observing JS capabilities of having multiple tasks completed on one line. Like we can do array.filter().sort().map() on one line, for example. Perhaps it can do the same with classes' methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the classList.replace() method

```js
element.classList.replace('some-class', 'new-class');
```

Comment: And that's when I realized I didn't specified my question well enough. Sure, ```.replace()``` also solves some cases, but say I need to add a few and remove a few, and that's where I don't know if I can do it on one line. I should specify the question. Thank you)

Comment: maybe a function and passing the arguments into the replace method?

Comment: feels like the end doesn't justify the means here, but I think that would be working though.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to add and remove multiple classes.

```js
const header = document.getElementById('header');

const addClasses = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello'];
const removeClasses = ['class1'];

header.className = header.className.split(' ')
                         .filter(c => !removeClasses.includes(c))
                         .concat(addClasses).join(' ');

// to show the classes on the #header element
document.body.innerHTML = header.className;
```

```html
<h1 id="header" class="class1 class2 class3"></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for the commitment to the task. That code should work. I guess though I was hoping for some syntax hack. Like that emmet thing for html, where the symbol "^" let's you "climb up" from the tag and write keep on writing other commands. Was wondering if there's the same thing to do.add() and then "climb back" to classList and then do .remove(). I guess there's no such thing so far.

Comment: _Was wondering if there's the same thing to do.add() and then "climb back" to classList and then do .remove()_ - you can't do that because `.add()` method returns `undefined`